# Django two ForeignKey from same model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

In `Pegawai` model, I need two `ForeignKey`s to:

1. `Jabatan` model
2. `unit_kerja` field of `Jabatan` model

How to apply these for my `Pegawai` model? Only the first one worked.

Here is my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.
class UnitKerja(models.Model):
    nama_unit_kerja     = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("users:unitkerja")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nama_unit_kerja

class Jabatan(models.Model):
    nama_jabatan        = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    level_jabatan       = models.IntegerField()
    unit_kerja          = models.ForeignKey(UnitKerja, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("users:jabatan")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nama_jabatan

class Pegawai(models.Model):
        nip                 = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
        nama_pegawai        = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        alamat              = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        jabatan             = models.ForeignKey(Jabatan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        #this line#    
        unit_kerja          = models.ForeignKey(Jabatan.unit_kerja, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("users:pegawai")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pegawai
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a foreign key to a field, but you don't need it anyway. You can always access the `UnitKerja` instance by using multiple traversal, for example:

```
my_unit_kerja = my_pegawai.jabatan.unit_kerja
```

Or you can have a helper property, if the above is too much work:

```
class Pegawai(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def unit_kerja(self):
        return self.jabatan.unit_kerja
```

and then simply use

```
my_pegawai.unit_kerja
```

Comment: honestly, i don't get about "my_pegawai.unit_kerja" part. How to apply it to my code?

Comment: You should add the `@property` to your `Pegawai` class as I described above. Then any `Pegawai` instance (`my_pegawai` in my example) will have access to that property.